# Model Validation on Dynamic type property in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to implement a model validation logic on a model entity that contains a model property of string type which represents other property's data type (e.g. Boolean, float, integer, datetime, string).

I want to find out the options available, or potentially the best option.

Below is the model entity:

```
public class CarEditViewModel
   {
        public List<CarParameter> CarParameters {get;set;}
        //other properties
   }

public class CarParameter
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual bool ShowHide { get; set; }
    public virtual string DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public virtual string DataType { get; set; }  //can be type of Boolean, float, integer, datetime, string
}
```

As shown above, the DataType represents the data type of DefaultValue property. The CarEditViewModel is used on MVC edit view. CarEditViewModel contains a collection of CarParameter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to create that as an enum.

If you are using MVC 3, checkout `IValidatableObject`.

[How do I use IValidatableObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400542/how-do-i-use-ivalidatableobject)