# 'System.Guid' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

EDIT:
Calling

```
  var _data = context.Database.SqlQuery<InfoViewModel>(sql).FirstOrDefault();
```

if I ran the below sql in the sql management studio and its works without throwing any error but if I have the same query called using EF its throwing the below error message:

here is my SQL:

```
SELECT 
 FROM dbo.Clients LEFT OUTER JOIN  
 dbo.aspnet_Users AS c ON dbo.Clients.CollectionsAssignedTo = c.UserId 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.aspnet_Users AS b ON dbo.Clients.Auditors_Key = b.UserId 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.aspnet_Users AS a ON dbo.Clients.AcctRep = a.UserId 
 WHERE dbo.Clients.ClientPKID = 'ce723426-dert-4c36-980a-f5181870d0d4'
```

> The cast to value type 'System.Guid' failed because the materialized
>   value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query
>   must use a nullable type

Comment: How do you call it from the code?

Comment: that is not a valid GUID -- you can't have letters after 'f' in a GUID it is hex

Comment: http://guid.us/Test/GUID... This relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187576/validation-of-guid

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even with this guid `ce723426-bfbe-4c48-980a-f5181870d0b4`

Comment: @StuartLC: please reply as answer and I will accept as answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is caused because one of `Guid` columns returned from your Sql query is NULL, and cannot be bound to your `InfoViewModel` entity because the matching property is defined as `Guid`, not `Nullable<Guid>` or `Guid?`.

A likely culprit here is that if a `Left Outer Join` fails to match, all columns in the right hand side table will be returned NULL. You haven't provided the SELECT columns, so we can only speculate, but for instance:

```
SELECT c.UserId, ... SomeOther columns
 FROM dbo.Clients 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.aspnet_Users AS c ON dbo.Clients.CollectionsAssignedTo = c.UserId
 ...
```

Here, if there is a Row in `dbo.Clients` with a value for `CollectionsAssignedTo` which does not have a corresponding `dbo.aspnet_Users` row with the same `c.UserId`, a row will be returned, however the `c.UserId` column will be NULL, and you will receive the error mentioned in your question. (The mere presence of LOJ over INNER JOIN could imply that failed joins are expected).

Comment: its just work me, i added .DefaultIfEmpty().FirstOrDefault(); end of linq query. because linq query can not return null if no record match in joining, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your query returns a `null` value in one of the `Guid` columns. That `null` value cannot be put into a `Guid` property in your DTO class `InfoViewModel`. How would you convert `null` to `Guid`? Impossible.

Make the property accept `null` values.