# MVC 3 Custon Date Validation (Between two other Date)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a DateTime, and need to validate that ...
I need that my DateTime stay Between two other Datetime (dynamic)...

How Can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).  It gives you a lot more control over your validation.

With FluentValidation, you would do something like this (where MyDateTime, date1, and date2 are properties of your MyModel class) :

```
public class MyModelValidator : AbstractValidator<MyModel> {
    public MyValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.MyDateTime).InclusiveBetween(date1, date2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mystere...
I tried Fluent Validation on my class... It showed the erros(client validation) fine with NotEmpty() method.... But usign RuleFor(x => x.MyDate).GreaterThan(new DateTime(2010, 6, 21)).LessThan(new DateTime(2010, 12, 17)) it did not did the client validation... How can I show the validation message in that case?

Comment: @Paul - Yes, GreaterThan, LessThan, and Must do not have client validation equivelents.  You can use .InclusiveBetween, and that should work client-side.

Comment: Thanks... But now I did that : 
 RuleFor(x => x.MyDate).InclusiveBetween(new DateTime(2010, 6, 21), new DateTime(2010, 12, 17)).WithMessage("Error");
And the error is fired always, no matter what date I choose... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a custom ValidationAttribute

```
   public sealed class Date1Attribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string date2Property { get; set; }
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // Compare the date
        string date2String = HttpContext.Current.Request[date2Property];
        DateTime date1 = (DateTime)value;
        DateTime date2 = DateTime.Parse(date2String);

        return date1 >= date2;
    }
}
```

or if you are using a datepicker, you can restrict the minDate and maxDate like this:

```
   $('#date1').datepicker({
    constrainInput: true, 
    dateFormat: 'D, dd M yy',
    // Once change, set date2 min date
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        $('#date2').datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
       }
    });

   $('#date2').datepicker({
    constrainInput: true, 
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: 'D, dd M yy'
   });
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: Note: The datepicker doesn't prevent you from typing in a date outside that range, it just disables dates in picker that are not in the range.  Also, you have to implement the client-side validation manually.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement [IValidatableObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3401178/26226).

Comment: Note: IValidatableObject does not support client-side validation

Comment: Good point. Another option is a custom validation attribute, which can support client side validation.