# Why does MVC FluentValidation InclusiveBetween always Fires Error with DateTime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

If I have a property in a view model like:

```
 [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
 public DateTime? MyDate{ get; set; }
```

And a validation rule like this:

```
public class YourDetailsViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<YourDetailsViewModel>
{
    public YourDetailsViewModelValidator()
    {           
        RuleFor(x => x.MyDate)                
            .InclusiveBetween(startDate, endDate)
               .WithMessage("error");
    }                       
}
```

Why does the error fire regardless of what date is input?

I did see a similar thing was happening [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361553/mvc-3-custon-date-validation-between-two-other-date)but the answer was ultimately accepted so I'm hoping it can be made to work properly.

Comment: Did you said about fails on client-side or server-side and did you check value binding is correct?

Comment: its on the client side.  it all seems to be bound properly.

Answer (score 0):

Error can be explained by difference in `jquery.validate` plugin date formatting and MVC helpers formatting. Just look in html generated by your view, and use

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="...")] // format string instead of dots
```

to make `data-val-min` and `data-val-max` attributes conform input `value` format (if they not, of course).

If value and validation attributes format are the same, but validation still fails - make sure that jquery.validate has appropriate format. In this case you should change ASP.NET MVC application culture to conform `jquery.validate` format, or vice versa — change `jquery.validate` format to conform application.

Similar questions asked on SO:

[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546971/mvc-4-how-to-validate-a-non-us-date-with-client-validation)

[Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779527/jquery-validation-and-mvc-3-how-to-change-date-format)

.NET date formatting options available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).