# Validating a view model after custom model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, custom-model-binder

I have a view model that implements `IValidatableObject` that contains a string and a collection of another view model, something like this:

```
public sealed class MainViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OtherViewModel> Others { get; set; }
}
```

My validation checks each object in `Others` against different rules using the contract provided by `IValidatableObject`:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    foreach (var other in this.Others)
    {
        // validate or yield return new ValidationResult
    }
}
```

Because of the complex structure of the real `MainViewModel` I have had to create a custom model binder which re-builds the model and assigns POST data to the relevant components. The problem that I'm getting is that nothing is getting validated resulting in validation errors at the context level as it violates certain database constraints and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - I assumed that `ModelState.IsValid` would invoke the `Validate` method on my view model but it doesn't seem to go down that way.

My model binder looks like this:

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    int modelId = (int)controllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"];

    // query the database and re-build the components of the view model

    // iterate the POST data and assign to the model where necessary

    // should I be calling something here to validate the model before it's passed to the controller?

    return model;
}
```

Any help appreciated!

**Validator.TryValidateObject**

OK, seems I'm a little closer. I can now get my `IValidatableObject` method to run by adding the following to my custom model binder:

```
var validationResults = new HashSet<ValidationResult>();
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, new ValidationContext(model, null, null), validationResults, true);
```

Seems that `Validator.TryValidateObject` invokes the validation method and setting the last parameter to `true` causes it to validate all properties. However, I'm now stuck with getting the `validationResults` to the controller so they can be used in a meaningful way.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145780/how-to-validate-my-model-in-a-custom-model-binder/77321423#77321423) if you want to redo validation after CustomModelBinding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I should have realised that I could use the `ModelState.AddModelError` through a custom binder, I've managed to get this working correctly now by adding the following to my custom model binder before returning the model to the controller:

```
var validationResults = new HashSet<ValidationResult>();
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, new ValidationContext(model, null, null), validationResults, true);
if (!isValid)
{
    foreach (var result in validationResults)
    {
        bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("", result.ErrorMessage);
    }
}

return model;
```

This now returns a list of all errors to my page and the `ModelState.IsValid` check on my controller action is now returning `false`.

Comment: where i need to place this code on : controller and action and in model binder and where ? Actually i am getting this error please help.

Comment: @Rajpurohit You'd put the above code in your custom model binder class.

Comment: in the formeach, you can also get the MemberNames.

string memberName = (result.MemberNames != null && result.MemberNames.Count() > 0) ? result.MemberNames.First() : string.Empty;
                    bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(memberName, result.ErrorMessage);

Answer (score 2):

Paul's great answer can be refactored into a generic validate-and-convert to `ModelState` method as follows (e.g. in a helper or `CustomModelBinder` base). In addition, the bindings to the validated properties are retained.

```
public static void DoValidation(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, 
                                IValidatableObject model)
{
    var validationResults = new HashSet<ValidationResult>();
    var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, 
        new ValidationContext(model, null, null), validationResults, true);
    if (!isValid)
    {
        var resultsGroupedByMembers = validationResults
            .SelectMany(_ => _.MemberNames.Select(
                 x => new {MemberName = x ?? "", 
                           Error = _.ErrorMessage}))
            .GroupBy(_ => _.MemberName);

        foreach (var member in resultsGroupedByMembers)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(
                member.Key,
                string.Join(". ", member.Select(_ => _.Error)));
        }
    }
}
```