# How do I add custom validation to a Razor page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working with MVC 4 for the first time. I have business logic that is a little complex but I would imagine not that uncommon.  I have items that can be resized within a specific range. The range depends upon the item.

```
public class MyItem
{
    public double Width { get; set; }

    public double MinWidth { get; set; }

    public double MaxWidth { get; set; }
}
```

`CustomWidth` when set by a user has to be within `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth` inclusively.  This seems like a common problem. I've tried the `CustomValidation` attribute but it only validates when I try to save the entity to my database (using Entity Framework).

This is the Razor page I'm working with.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post)) { 
<aside id="aside">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Width)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Width)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Width)
    </div>  

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Height)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Height)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Height)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Depth)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Depth)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Depth)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="save" />
</aside>
}
```

Comment: This would work, but I don't want to couple my data layer that closely to MVC.

Comment: It wouldn't couple the ui to the datalayer if you employed a view model

Comment: Point well taken, but it would still couple the validation into the view model a bit too much for comfort. I didn't realize that returning the model after the post call would report the errors. I've grokked that now thanks to @mrcolombo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do custom validation, you want to inherit from `IValidatableObject`.

**Note custom validation will happen after initial model validation is successful

```
    public class MyItem : IValidatableObject
        {
            public double Width { get; set; }

            public double MinWidth { get; set; }

            public double MaxWidth { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
           {
                // Custom validation
           }

}
```

[Example on how to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400542/how-do-i-use-ivalidatableobject)

Comment: Does this work with Razor in JavaScript?

Comment: NM, I just grokked the whole `ModelState.IsValid` thing. I don't need no stinkin' javascript anymore.  Thanks. :)

Comment: This does not work in Razor Pages, the Validate() is ignored. There is a duscussion on that https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4895