# ModelState fails when sharing a ViewModel in different Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, modelstate

I have a simple form that posts a ViewModel to an Action method. Before saving the information  the ModelState is checked with a standard `if(ModelState.IsValid)`. Then a new object is created and saved. Great, it works.

Recently another dev went in and created a new view with my original ViewModel. He also added a new [Required] property to the ViewModel to make his logic work.

By doing that his logic broke my initial logic. Because my initial view doesn't use his new Required property so `ModelState.IsValid` check now fails and my code doesn't run.

What is the best approach to take here ? Though I don't want to but should I get rid of ModelState.IsValid check on my Post actions or can I somehow flag his new property to Not be required when used in my original views or when being posted in my action method ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "What is the best approach" - slap the other developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute `[Bind(Exclude="")]` in your action method like below. Then, when you submit the form, model binder will ignore that property even it is required.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Exclude = "AdditionalProperty")]YourModel model)
{
  //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can derive the model from IValidatableObject, and then perform your own custom validations using

```
public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
}
```

[How do I use IValidatableObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400542/how-do-i-use-ivalidatableobject)

Edtied to add:  If it were me, it would seem to make more sense to have him create an inherited model from your model, even if it only has 1 property in it.  This would keep the native MVC validations working correctly with minimal effort on your part.

Answer (score 1):

you have two choice(to the best of my knowledge!), first you can unbind the that required property while posting it to the action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "RequiredProperty")]MyViewModel myViewModel)
    {
       if(ModelState.IsValid)
       {
         //
       }

    }
```

but you can solve this issue for your application by mapping the ViewModel to View in your get action, and send it to the view. try this [great](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/) article