# How to add additional validation to Model field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a second thing:

```
<td>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Number, titleHtmlAttrs)
</td>
<td>
    <span class="element-value2">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Number)
        @Html.ValidationTooltipFor(m => m.Number)
    </span>
</td>
```

And this is how this field looks like in model:

```
[Display(Name = "Special Number")]
[StringLength(20)]
public string Number { get; set; }
```

Which means that if I wanted to change this field, i can have any value from empty to 20.
It's ok, but now I need an additional validation.
In model I have some fields:

```
public DateTime? TimeOf { get; set; }
public bool HasType { get; set; }
```

New validation should work **ONLY** if TimeOf is not null and HasType is true. New validation should prevent empty values in Number. Basically, change (from empty to 20) to (from 1 to 20).

How could I correctly accomplish this?

P.S Sorry about my bad English.

Comment: Look at the [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue]` and `[RequiredIfNotEmpty]` validation attributes

Answer (score 2):

For complex validation logic, look at implementing [`IValidatableObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400542/how-do-i-use-ivalidatableobject) in your `ViewModel` and then you can place your conditional validation logic inside the `Validate` method. (Caveat, this is obviously server side)

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (this.HasType)
    {
       // Do other conditional validation
       if (validationFails)
       {
           yield return new ValidationResult("descriptive error goes here");
       }
    } 
    // Other validation here.
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** *It seems I have misunderstood the question. As the other answer has already pointed out, you could implement the IValidatableObject for achieving this. Something like:*

```
public class YourModelName : IValidatableObject
{
  [StringLength(20)]
  public string Number{ get; set; }

  [Required]
  public DateTime? TimeOf { get; set; }

  public bool HasType { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
  { 
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

    if (TimeOf != null && HasType)
       Validator.TryValidateProperty(this.Number,
            new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "Number" },
            results);    

    if (TimeOf == null) 
       results.Add(new ValidationResult("Date Time must have a value"));
    if (!HasType)
       results.Add(new ValidationResult("Must be true"));

    return results;
  }
```

}

**OLD ANSWER:**
*You could write your custom validator for more complex validation conditions. Something like:*

```
public class SomeCustomValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
   protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
      string number = value as string;
      if (value == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Can only be used on string properties");

      if (!value.IsEmpty && value.Length <= 20)
      {
          return ValidationResult.Success;
      }

      return new ValidationResult("Name must be a non-empty string smaller than 20 chars"));
   }
}
```

And for HasType, another custom one:

```
public class IsTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

  public override bool IsValid(object value)
  {
      if (value == null) return false;
      if (value.GetType() != typeof(bool)) throw new InvalidOperationException("can only be used on boolean properties.");

      return (bool) value == true;
  }

}
```

And on TimeOf you could use the required attribute to make sure it has a value:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Must have value")]
public DateTime? TimeOf {get;set;}
```

And use the custom attributes on the other two:

```
[SomeCustomValidator(ErrorMessage="Error msg...")]
public string Number {get;set;}

[IsTrueAttribute(ErrorMessage="Must be true")]
public bool HasType {get;set;}
```

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. OP wants `Number` to be required based on the value of the other properties. And your `SomeCustomValidator` does exactly what `[StringLength]` does but without client side validation