# MVC Client side validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have 3 textboxes ...one for day, second for month and third for year. I want to use mvc validation to check if one of this field is empty and then show *. Is it possible on button submit display just one error message if one of those fields are empty?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="dateofbirth" class="control-label col-lg-5">
        @Html.Label(@BetXOnline.TranslationProvider.Instance.GetTranslationMessage("BIRTHDATE")):
        @Html.ValidationMessage("*")
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Day, new { id = "day_birthdate", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Month, new { id = "month_birthdate", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Year, new { id = "year_birthdate", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
```

Comment: Implement IValidateableObject on Register class:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400542/how-do-i-use-ivalidatableobject

Answer (score 0):

In your module class on the property attached with textbox provide attribute `[Required]`.

than you can use of ValidationSummary which is already available in Asp.net MVC.

if you want to display message just beside file than do use `ValidationMessageFor`

Check : [ASP.NET MVC Client Side Validation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718004/ASP-NET-MVC-Client-Side-Validation)

class property definition for this

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Example

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
```

Comment: i dont want to use validation summary because i need to display error message next to label...i have another textboxes which i need to validate and show next to other labels..and if i use like u say i would get 3 error messages

Comment: but i want to check if textbox of day or month or year is empty and then call validationmessagefor... how can i do that?This is just for one field in your example

Comment: @None - you need to attached datanotation to proeprty as i given in my example

Comment: i have 3 field that i need to check... in your example its just one

Comment: @None - so have to do same thing for other two..as simple as that...check the link also given by me

Comment: yes but if i do that i will get 3 different messages for each filed but i want only one if fields are not populated

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `@ValidationMessageFor` for all fields under **same label**.

```
<label for="dateofbirth" class="control-label col-lg-5">
    @Html.Label(@BetXOnline.TranslationProvider.Instance.GetTranslationMessage("BIRTHDATE"))
    :
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Register.Day,"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Register.Month,"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Register.Year,"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</label>
```

Comment: @None Yes, for each field. If one fields is correct you will get only 2.

Comment: i want to get only one error message if fields are incorrect