# How to validate multiple textboxes with MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have three textboxes and i need to check if one of field is not enter and display error(just one error). Is this possible with MVC validation or i need javascript validation?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Day, new { id = "day_birthdate" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Month, new { id = "month_birthdate"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Year, new { id = "year_birthdate" })
```

Model:

```
    public int? Day { get; set; }

    public int? Month { get; set; }

    public int? Year { get; set; }
```

I dont want to get three different errors...I dont want this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Day, new { id = "day_birthdate" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Register.Day)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Month, new { id = "month_birthdate"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Register.Month)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Year, new { id = "year_birthdate" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Register.Year)
```

Comment: Can you show your model? that is where you should put your validation.

Comment: This is about your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169284/mvc-client-side-validation/30169499#30169499)?

Comment: @Donal there is my model...

Comment: Well it seems you really need all those inputs to come up with a Date so it's weird to have things like `nullable` and `[Required]`.  Does `DateTime` work better in your model? You can map/validate from whatever input fields on the front end to it....

Comment: i know that is better but i need to do this with three textboxes

Comment: Yes it's possible, but why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can also add an error message to the model state like:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Day", "Something is wrong with Day");
```

To bind the above error to a specific property you specify the property name as the first parameter => "Day".

Answer (score 0):

```
in the class model for Register,add
[Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
public int Day
{
get;
set;
}


     to get [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")] this add namespace 
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;  
        in controller,also check if(modelstate.isvalid==true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
public int? Day { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
public int? Month { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
public int? Year { get; set; }
```

Comment: I want only one error if those fields are empty...not three...read my question

Comment: @None in this case please edit your question and make more clear ! I don't think that what you're asking for is available in .NET MVC, so you should implement a custom validation. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242847/model-validation-asp-net-mvc-3-conditional-required-attribute
I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to specify in your model which fields are required.

```
[Required]
public int? Day { get; set; }

[Required]    
public int? Month { get; set; }

[Required]
public int? Year { get; set; }
```

*you need to import namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to get `[Required]`

then in view you need to add the validation message

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Day, new { id = "day_birthdate" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Register.Day)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Month, new { id = "month_birthdate"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Register.Month)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Year, new { id = "year_birthdate" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Register.Year)
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: it will work its just i want only one error for those three fields and not one error for each field if u know what i mean

Comment: i need only *(only one) if year OR month OR day is empty