# c# web api request validation filter, context values empty - arguments list isn't

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-web-api

I'm using C# web api and want to create a filter to all requests.

I have a designated class to every request so I just want to add some data annotations and get the validation over with.

The problem is that I'm getting `true` every time on `actionContext.ModelState.IsValid`

I have added my filter in the config:

```
config.Filters.Add(new RequestValidationFilter());
```

validation method looks like every other in the web

```
public class RequestValidationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            var errors = actionContext.ModelState
                                      .Values
                                      .SelectMany(m => m.Errors
                                                        .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));

            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);

            actionContext.Response.ReasonPhrase = string.Join("\n", errors);
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following method:

```
[HttpPost, Route("User/Login")]
public async Task<Responses.Login> Login(Requests.Login request)
{
      ...//some login logic
}
```

And also, I have my model which is:

```
public class Requests
{
    public class Login
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email address  cannot be empty!")]
[MinLength(5)]
            public string Email;
        [Required]
        public string Password;
    }
}
```

I'm sending both an empty request or request which `Email` and `Password` are null and still the  `actionContext.ModelState.IsValid` evaluate it as `true`

Attached is an image when email was sent but password wasn't.

[image]

Following a comment, here is my request via Advanced Rest Client chrome plugin

[image]
**NOTE**

the image actually shows that Keys and Values are empty when in fact they are supplied..

**EDIT**

number of things i've also tried:

1. removing all other filters, why? maybe the context was messed up by another reading.
2. sending valid request in terms of fields, but email was 1 char long.why? maybe `Required`is working differently than others, still nothing about the min-length issue.
3. instead of nested objects, i created a seperate stand-alone class for the `Login` object. why? thought maybe the fact that it's nested the validation is not recursive.
4. Looping the `Arguments` list one-by-one and validate as object, answer is always true. never fails, why? cause Im almost admitting defeat.
5. instead of adding filter to config as i described in the question, tried `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new RequestValidationFilter());` instead

Comment: There's a lot of good info on this post.  You can try implementing IValidatableObject and ModelState should look at the object's Validate method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400542/how-do-i-use-ivalidatableobject

Comment: i really want to avoid making something manual.
can i implement whats in there and still work with the custom error message and all the tools that annontion provide me?
Its important for me to implement the validation preior to the invocation on the method in the controller

Comment: This post might be helpful: http://www.strathweb.com/2012/10/clean-up-your-web-api-controllers-with-model-validation-and-null-check-filters/

Comment: @CodingGorilla well. unfortunatly, it didn't. the only difference there that they built another filter for null handling. that's not my concern here.
if you can give another suggestion or a feedback it would be lovely

Comment: @OriRefael Sorry, I've never used this feature myself, I just found that after a quick search and thought it might be helpful to you.

Comment: Someone summon JohnSkeet please. he will know :)

Comment: Are you able to get the model state validating correctly in the controller method itself, using ModelState.IsValid? Remove the filter attribute for now.

Comment: @OriRefael Can you also put up details on how you are calling into this API? The issue may lie there, because you mentioned email only has one character. This filter code checks out :)

Comment: @OpenderSingh added image in question about the request. also added the part i forgot to add in question regarding the length of email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `{ get; set; }` after your model properties:

```
public class Login
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email address cannot be empty!")]
    [MinLength(5)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

This is necessary because the default model validation for ASP.NET only includes properties with a public `get` method. From [PropertyHelper.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Common/blob/9a8cf5ea9ca602ed256e97a9baa2d831c763356d/src/Microsoft.Extensions.PropertyHelper.Sources/PropertyHelper.cs), here's some of the code which determines whether a property on the model will be included in validation:

```
// Indexed properties are not useful (or valid) for grabbing properties off an object.
private static bool IsInterestingProperty(PropertyInfo property)
{
    return property.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 &&
        property.GetMethod != null &&
        property.GetMethod.IsPublic &&
        !property.GetMethod.IsStatic;
}
```

This method is used to filter the properties that are used in the default model binding in MVC/Web API. Notice that it's checking whether the GetMethod exists on the property and that it's public. Since your class didn't have the `get` methods on its properties, they were being ignored.

If you want to know more, you can kill a lot of time looking through the [ASP.NET MVC source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc). I think the code on github is for a newer version of ASP.NET, but it seems like a lot of the same logic applies in the version you are using.

Comment: Good spotting! I think this is the issue. Only difference I can see.

Comment: Bullcrap! i can't bealieve it was it. i thought to myself: "what the hell?" and you just spotted it. amazing. can you explain?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the validator not being able to see the fields in your class unless they have a getter method. I will play around with it later and see if I can come up with a real explanation