# How to validate model depends on bool datatype value using asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a model using asp.net core web API and I have to validate the property depends on bool data type property value.

If the `IsWaitingList` property is true , the `WaitingListEncounterOrOtherEncounter` property is required property, else it's not a mandatory field.

```
public class CenterConfiguration
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public bool? IsWaitingList { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter waiting list encounter or other encounter")]
        public int WaitingListEncounterOrOtherEncounter { get; set; }
    }
```

If anybody knows, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `IValidatableObject` to check complex validation conditions.

```
public class CenterConfiguration : IValidatableObject {
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public bool? IsWaitingList { get; set; }
    public int? WaitingListEncounterOrOtherEncounter { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
         if (IsWaitingList && !WaitingListEncounterOrOtherEncounter.HasValue) {
             yield return new ValidationResult(
                 "Please enter waiting list encounter or other encounter",
                 new[] { "WaitingListEncounterOrOtherEncounter" }
             );
         }
    }
}
```

Also note that I changed `WaitingListEncounterOrOtherEncounter` from `int` to `int?` so you can actually leave this value blank.

See also [How do I use IValidatableObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400542/how-do-i-use-ivalidatableobject)