# Dynamic expression as data-annotations attribute values

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, globalization

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 project in which I use annotations to validate a currency field, like this:

```
public class Record {
    public const string CurrencyRegex = @"^[$]?\d+[,.]?\d?\d? ?[€$]?$";

[RegularExpression(Record.CurrencyRegex, ErrorMessage = "Invalid currency format")]
public string Budget { get; set; }
```

The problem is the decimal separator (`[,.]?\d?\d?`) is not perfect. I need the expression be sensible of the current context culture. If is UK/US, the decimal separator should be validated as `.`, but id there, say FR culture, the decimal should be considered as `,`

How can I use a "context-dependent constant" as `RegularExpression` attribute value, if possible?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Any values passed to attributes must be compile-time constants. But `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` or similar is a runtime variable.

What you can do is define the `Budget` as `decimal` or `double` and let the ModelBinder parse the input string using the current culture. (You will have to transport the currency symbol in an additional field.)

Or handle the validation by implementing [`IValidatableObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400542/how-do-i-use-ivalidatableobject) on the model and remove the `[RegularExpression]`:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Record : IValidatableObject {

     public string Budget { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {

        var currentDecimalSeparator =
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;

        // no need to espace literal dot '.' 
        // because it is used inside a character class '[.]'
        var currencyPattern = @"^[$]?\d+[" + currentDecimalSeparator + @"]?\d?\d? ?[€$]?$";

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(Budget, currencyPattern)) {
             yield return new ValidationResult(
                 $"Invalid currency format (use '{currentDecimalSeparator}' for decimal places).",
                 new[] { "Budget" }
             );
        }
     }
}
```