# How can I use validation in self property object in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a little ERP to my company and I crashed into a problem about validation:

I have self property object like:

```
public class Person
{
   [Required]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Phone { get; set; }
   public bool HasContact { get; set; }

   public Person Contact { get; set; }
}
```

If HasContact is false, I don`t want put a Contact. If is true, I want.

The problem is my ModelState never is Valid, because Name is Required and Contact self implement Person.

I would like to set condition if HasContact is true, my application try validate the Contact property. If is not, set Valid and execute controller correct.

Is it possible or am I crazy?

Comment: I'm very confused on the question. I'd recommend trying to explain it better. I am unsure of what your other classes are etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your object implement [IValidatableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx).  It lets you implement your own validation logic so you can ignore properties as necessary (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400542/how-do-i-use-ivalidatableobject)).

Your code might be something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    if (this.HasContact)
    {
        Validator.TryValidateProperty(this.Contact,
            new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "Contact" },
            results);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...


But, I'm not sure if this is the answer... If I use validate method every validation will blocked, correct?


I will need make every validation manually. I want correct validate the Contact...


Probably I didnt explane clearly my question... I will make some tests and Will return the results...

Thanks again...

Comment: If you implement `IValidatableObject` it hooks into the system already in place for doing validations.  So you won't have to call `myObject.Validate(...)`.  You would just do `if (ModelState.IsValid)` just like you always have.