# Is it possible to make a required attribute not required in a HTTP request?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a attribute in a form which the attribute is required. I need this required in all my requests except for one request where because of an exception I don't want the attribute to be not required. Is this even possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Use a *different* form or DTO. Even with the same form you probably have different validation rules for the `New` and `Edit` forms.

Comment: can you specify on what case you need to make your required attribute optional?

Comment: It is for a post request

Comment: As above - you just need a separate form and separate rules for server side validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I absolutely agree with **Panagiotis Kanavos** that you need to use an another DTO object in this case. This would make your code much easier to read for new developer.
2. You can implement IValidatableObject interface on your DTO object. See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3401178/2903893). *This seems very similar to what your are searching for.*
3. Another approach (although, I don't recommend it in this case) is to use some library that do similar validation but you can add some logic in validation. For instance, take a look at [FLUENT VALIDATION](https://fluentvalidation.net/start)